# Proof that parallelogram equals 2x2 determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]
[image]
I do not understand one sentence: "Figure 5.3b shows that the solid parallelogram areas add to the dotted parallelogram area (because the two triangles completed by the dotted lines are the same)."

Can someone help me understand this? I do not see that A + A' = area of the dotted parallelogram.

Answer (score 2):

You can cut out the almost flat triangle at the bottom and paste it back at the top, it doesn't change the area to cut/paste and what you get is the dotted parallelogram.

Great picture by the way, very enlightening regarding the properties of the determinant.

Comment: Can you give me the coordinates of the "almost flat triangle" you refer to?

Comment: @user3180 $(0,0), (x_1,y_1), (x_1+x_1',y_1+y_1')$.

Answer (score 1):

The dotted parallelogram's area is the sum of areas of solid ones plus the area of the upper triangle minus the area of the lower triangle. Since the areas of the two triangles are the same, you get the result.

Comment: Why is the first statement true? I don't see it.

Comment: Just look at the picture on the right.

Comment: It's not clear to me. You are saying essentially that the sum of the surface area of the 3 faces A, A' and the top right triangle equal the sum of the surface area of the bottom triangle plus the dotted parallelogram. I'm not sure why that must be true.

Comment: The picture shows that in order to obtain the dotted parallelogram you should join two solid ones then cut off (with scissors) the lower triangle and put that triangle on top.

Comment: WOW! OK. My brain automatically made it into a 3d thing. But there is no Z-dimension here.

Comment: Thank you, this was bugging me because typically dotted lines give depth perception. But that makes no sense as indicated by the points which are only in (x,y).